# Creating CGPDFDocument from a URL yields errors in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, swift3

The below block of code yields these two errors when I try to build. Can anybody help me out? Xcode 8 had its way with my project using its migrator and I haven't seen this error before.

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!;
    var pdf:CGPDFDocument = CGPDFDocument(url);
```

1. `error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGPDFDocument' with an argument list of type '(URL)'`
2. `note: overloads for 'CGPDFDocument' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (CGDataProvider), (CFURL)`

Answer (score 3):

Hello it should like this below.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
fileprivate var pdfDoc: CGPDFDocument
pdfDoc = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL)!
```